# How do i use nth-child to the icons while hovering?

Tags: html, css

How do I use nth-child technique so that each time use hover a particular icon, it should change color and pop-up without disturbing the others. I tried and the effects are working for every icons not on a particular one.

```css
.icon ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  margin: 30px;
}

.icon {
  background: #000;
}

.icon ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: crimson;
  padding: 10px;
}

.icon ul li a i {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.icon ul li a:nth-child(1):hover {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?
family=Berkshire+Swash|Boogaloo|Lobster+Two|Raleway|Amaranth" 
rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-
awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<label><strong>Or follow Us -</strong></label>
<div class="icon">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="https://facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://twitter.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://linkedin.com"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://Youtube.com"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://instagram.com"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: your code didnt work because **a** is always the 1st child inside the element **li**,  transfer the nth-child to **li** instead, also add the **font-size: ;** on **a** instead inside the **:hover** so it wont disturb others

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `:nth-child(1)` on the `li` and not on the `a` element. Like this:

```
.icon ul li:nth-child(1) a:hover
```

This selects the first `li` element among a collection of sibling `li`'s. What you were trying to do was to select the first `a` element in a collection of sibling `a`'s, but there is only one sibling `a` in each `li`.

---

Full demo:

```css
.icon ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  margin: 30px;
}

.icon {
  background: #000;
}

.icon ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: crimson;
  padding: 10px;
}

.icon ul li a i {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.icon ul li:nth-child(1) a:hover {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?
family=Berkshire+Swash|Boogaloo|Lobster+Two|Raleway|Amaranth" 
rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-
awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<label><strong>Or follow Us -</strong></label>
<div class="icon">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="https://facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://twitter.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://linkedin.com"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://Youtube.com"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://instagram.com"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thnx but 1 problem remains. while hovering the other icon's sizes also increases along with the div. should i have a height for the div?

Answer (score 0):

Assign font-size to only one element either **a** or **i**. And use `li:nth-child(1)`

To make font larger on hover, instead of increasing font-size,
Try Css scale().

```
-ms-transform: scale(1.2); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2); /* Safari */
    transform: scale(1.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The nth-child declaration should be based on `li`. In your code, you put it for the anchor tag. Here is the correct code.

```css
.icon ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  margin: 30px;
}

.icon {
  background: #000;
}

.icon ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: crimson;
  padding: 10px;
}

.icon ul li a i {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.icon ul li:nth-child(1) a:hover {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 25px;
}
.icon ul li:nth-child(2) a:hover {
  color: green;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?
family=Berkshire+Swash|Boogaloo|Lobster+Two|Raleway|Amaranth" 
rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-
awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<label><strong>Or follow Us -</strong></label>
<div class="icon">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="https://facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://twitter.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://linkedin.com"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://Youtube.com"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://instagram.com"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.icon ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  margin: 30px;
}
.icon {
  background: #000;
}
.icon ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: crimson;
  padding: 10px;
}
.icon ul li a {
  font-size: 25px;
}
.icon ul li:nth-child(1) a:hover {
  color: blue;
}
.icon ul li:nth-child(2) a:hover {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?
family=Berkshire+Swash|Boogaloo|Lobster+Two|Raleway|Amaranth" 
rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-
awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<label><strong>Or follow Us -</strong></label>
<div class="icon">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="https://facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://twitter.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://linkedin.com"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://Youtube.com"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://instagram.com"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.icon ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  margin: 30px;
}

.icon {
  background: #000;
}

.icon ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.icon ul li a i {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: crimson;
  -webkit-transition:transform .3s;
}

.icon ul li a i:hover {
  color: blue;
  -webkit-transform:scale(1.2);
  -webkit-transition:transform .3s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?
family=Berkshire+Swash|Boogaloo|Lobster+Two|Raleway|Amaranth" 
rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-
awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<label><strong>Or follow Us -</strong></label>
<div class="icon">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="https://facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://twitter.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://linkedin.com"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://Youtube.com"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://instagram.com"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

no need nth-child